# Google Earth Engine -hourly timestep

Tags: google-earth-engine, select, time

Does anybody know how to select 3-hourly time steps in a dataset on Google Earth Engine?

Here is what I have tried

```js
    // A function to compute CF_solar for every time step at which irradiation and temperature are available (3-hourly)
var CF_solar2 = function(image) {
  return image.expression(
    '(1-beta*(c1 + c2*T + c3*G - T_ref) + gamma*log10(G+1))*G/G_ref',
    {
      'beta': 0.0045,
      'c1': -3.75,
      'c2': 1.14,
      'c3': 0.0175,
      'T_ref': 25,
      'gamma': 0.1,
      'G_ref': 1000,
      'T': image.select('Tair_f_inst').subtract(273.15),
      'G': image.select('SWdown_f_tavg'),
    }).rename("CF2").set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this answers you question, as it is not perfectly clear to me.

I see from your other question that you're dataset is imported as follows:

```js
// import geometry (point to zoom in to)
var home_coords = ee.Geometry.Point([-7.6, 54.4])
var region = home_coords.buffer(20000);

// load image stack for one year
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H")
   .filterDate('2010-12-01', '2010-12-31')
   .filterBounds(home_coords);

print(dataset);
```

Each image consists then of an start hour (0-21) and an end hour three hours later. If your question is that you only want, for example, the images starting at start_hour == 0, then you should at this line in your code. Edit the zero to another hour (e.g. 3) if you want a colleciton of images with start hour 3.

```js
 var filteredDataset = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('start_hour', 0));
 print(filteredDataset);
```

If this does not perfectly solve your problem, please specify your question by editing your first post and I guess it will be solved easily.

Comment: Hi thanks so much, that explains things. I wanted my code to represent every 3 hours across the month (so the timeseries would have data at every 3 hours). But now I see that this is what it was doing anyway - with 240 points over dates 1-31 in december.